# Can I safely delete vite.config.ts.timestamp* files?

Tags: vite, sveltekit

I'm working on a SvelteKit project and I have a bunch of vite.config files:

```
ll vite.config.*
```

Output:

```
.rw-rw-r-- 1.3k sas 30 May 19:49 vite.config.ts
.rw-rw-r-- 5.3k sas 19 Jun 18:09 vite.config.ts.timestamp-1687208977000-d9424581b6c6.mjs
.rw-rw-r-- 5.3k sas 19 Jun 18:09 vite.config.ts.timestamp-1687208977001-6954a6ac5ac19.mjs
.rw-rw-r-- 5.3k sas 19 Jun 18:09 vite.config.ts.timestamp-1687208977001-9201cfcc774c9.mjs
.rw-rw-r-- 5.3k sas 19 Jun 18:09 vite.config.ts.timestamp-1687208977001-ad78163483ceb.mjs
.rw-rw-r-- 5.3k sas 19 Jun 18:09 vite.config.ts.timestamp-1687208977007-4c080a380ebd9.mjs
.rw-rw-r-- 5.3k sas 19 Jun 18:09 vite.config.ts.timestamp-1687208977007-4cf3e5ed6cf92.mjs
.rw-rw-r-- 5.3k sas 19 Jun 18:09 vite.config.ts.timestamp-1687208977007-a642b2ba2f4cd.mjs
.rw-rw-r-- 5.3k sas 19 Jun 18:09 vite.config.ts.timestamp-1687208977007-bcfada510dd4.mjs
.rw-rw-r-- 5.3k sas 19 Jun 18:09 vite.config.ts.timestamp-1687208977007-d88f9fb0e8e01.mjs
.rw-rw-r-- 5.3k sas 19 Jun 18:09 vite.config.ts.timestamp-1687208977007-f64dce72b77b8.mjs
.rw-rw-r-- 5.3k sas 19 Jun 18:09 vite.config.ts.timestamp-1687208977008-6e0d56c4a9827.mjs
```

Can I safely remove them (or even better, prevent them from being generated at all)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are just temporary compiled files if the config is written in TypeScript. They usually should be cleaned up right away automatically. I guess if errors occur or the process is interrupted otherwise, they can remain.

They can just be deleted manually.

(See also [this issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/13267), maybe not all conditions which cause the files to remain have or can be fixed.)